# change the default color of drop down button

Tags: html, css

I need to change default color of drop down button.`

```
<button class="btn-btn-primary dropdown-toogle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Course
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Math</a></li>
</ul>
```

I get drop down button in default color. I need to change it in different color

Comment: what kind of color you want

Comment: In your code, you have `dropdown-toogle`. Should this be `dropdown-toggle`?

Comment: If you use bootstrap, then you should read documentation for a start. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

Use `Bootstrap` classes :-

> - btn-primary
> - btn-success
> - btn-danger
> - btn-info
> - btn-warning

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Course
                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Math</a></li>
                        </UL>
<button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">success
                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
<button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">warning
                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
<button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">info
                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
<button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">danger
                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
```

Comment: ok good, but i want select course is in blue color not in red, how to change that  one

Comment: @KhanalWeb use btn-primary class check the answer again

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this
    either you can change the button class "btn-info" it is the bootstrap btn class and it  will change the btn color in blue(Cyan) or you can create you can put your own class beside btn class and give that class any color according to your need.

```
<pre>
<button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toogle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Course<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Math</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

<pre>

<pre>
<style>
.my-btn{
  background:red !important;
}
</style>

<button class="btn btn-info my-btn dropdown-toogle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Course<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Math</a></li>
      </ul>
</pre>
```